# Beamer outline disappearing

Tags: beamer, lyx

I'm using making my first set of Beamer slides for an upcoming presentation and noticed the outline on the top of the slides doesn't have the same coloring as that shown for the particular theme I'm using.

[image]

This image is what the outline looks at the beginning of the presentation and when I get to the section "Introduction" the highlight color changes to black, so it disappears.

[image]

The Warsaw theme though shows this going to a brighter white? Any idea on why this might be happening? I'm working in Lyx but exported to a `.tex` file to see if that might help, but nothing changed. I'm also on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

In attempting to create a MWE I found the following code is what causes the problem

`\ifx\hypersetup\undefined
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true,pdftitle={The LyX User's Guide},
 pdfauthor={LyX Team},
 pdfsubject={LyX},
 pdfkeywords={LyX},
 linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue, pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}
  }
\else
  \hypersetup{unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true,pdftitle={The LyX User's Guide},
 pdfauthor={LyX Team},
 pdfsubject={LyX},
 pdfkeywords={LyX},
 linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue, pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}
\fi`

This is being put in by Lyx. How do I change this?

---

**Solution**
In Lyx under Document -> Settings -> PDF Properties if you uncheck the box Customize Hyperref Options, you'll get the correct output for your Beamer presentations.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @samcarter see my update for the MWE

Comment: You could simply remove all this code from your code (it does not make any sense with beamer), than the linkcolour would not be altered

Comment: `linkcolor=black` Does not  tell you anything?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all this messing with the `\hypersetup` from your document. Beamer makes a lot of effort to set all colours suitable to the current theme and your new setup just throws away all these settings and makes the links black.

As a side effect you will also get more sensible pdf meta information which will contain the author and title of the presentation instead of these uninformative lyx stuff.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usetheme{Warsaw}

%\ifx\hypersetup\undefined
%  \AtBeginDocument{%
%    \hypersetup{unicode=true,
% bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
% breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true,pdftitle={The LyX User's Guide},
% pdfauthor={LyX Team},
% pdfsubject={LyX},
% pdfkeywords={LyX},
% linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue, pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}
%  }
%\else
%  \hypersetup{unicode=true,
% bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
% breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true,pdftitle={The LyX User's Guide},
% pdfauthor={LyX Team},
% pdfsubject={LyX},
% pdfkeywords={LyX},
% linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue, pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}
%\fi

\begin{document}

\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{other section}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Lyx and haven't found where to edit this code. I only found it by exporting to a Tex file. Would you know where I could remove this section of code in Lyx?

Comment: @BoJohnson No idea, I'm not using lyx.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: @BoJohnson Reduce your presentation to that two frames of samcarter example and then edit  your question to post the complete  `.lyx` file, not the exported `.tex`. This way anyone with lyx could load it with lyX and see exactly how your file is configured. The fragment that you show seem the result of play with the PDF properties menu, but it could be also a custom change in the LaTeX  preamble or even an evil red text (ERT) box.